# RSS from *.aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, flexlm

How I can read rss  [from this page](http://www.cyprusrecruiter.com/rss.aspx?q=&p=0)!
The page don't give you access to xml file, only give option to downloads rss.aspx page which inside look like xml file.
Perfect way if i can transform rss.aspx to rss.xml

Answer (score 1):

Change the extension of downloaded file to .xml (just rename the file)...

If you want this file to be opened instead of downloaded, try to change Response.ContentType at server side. Though this will not change the extension of the file. Here is a [link](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/381.cfm) to good article about proper content-type of RSS feeds.

If you want to change the extension of this file at server side - perhaps you will have to create HttpHandler.